# How to preview uploaded non-public website?

Tags: website, google-cloud-storage

How do I preview a website I uploaded to Google Cloud? I do not want it to be publicly accessible yet and want to see first how it looks and loads. I created the CNAME record, and bucket, enabled the computing API, and more. Where and how do I view it without it being public yet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about just reviewing one initial time (as opposed to having a system in place that lets you stage and review content every time you update the website). If that's the case, you could leave the bucket IAM configuration so it is readable only by you/your team, upload the content, review the website, and then change the IAM policy to make it publicly readable.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Yes, I would like to review it one time, at least, as opposed to an ongoing update-review system.  It may seem like a silly question, but how do I go about reviewing the website? Where would I go in the Cloud console?